# Cosine Similarity on Text

Tags: nlp, cosine-similarity

I have a dataset with one column containing course names. I need to write a code to allow for a query search that returns the 10 most similar courses to the given query.

Below is the code that I tried. However, it is returning the query itself with the score of 1.0. Kindly help me out with this!

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# List of documents to search

documents = list_of_names

# Transform documents into vectors using the CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

# Define the search query
query = 'aws'

# Transform the query into a vector using the fitted vectorizer
query_vector = vectorizer.transform([query])

# Calculate the cosine similarity between the query vector and all document vectors
similarity_scores = cosine_similarity(query_vector, vectorizer.transform(documents))

# Find the indices of the top 10 most similar documents
most_similar_indices = np.argsort(similarity_scores)[:, :-11:-1]

# Print the top 10 most similar documents and their similarity scores
for i, indices in enumerate(most_similar_indices[0]):
    print('Rank:', i+1)
    print('Document:', documents[indices])
    print('Similarity score:', similarity_scores[0][indices])
    print('---')
```